# Python - Sort Lines in File by Regex Date Match

Tags: python, regex, datetime

I have a file (based on a class project) of scraped Tweets. At this point lines in the file look like:

```
@soandso something something <a href="http://pic.twitter.com/aphoto</a><a href="a link" target="_blank">Permalink</a> 1:40 PM - 17 Feb 2016<br><br>
@soandso something something <a href="http://pic.twitter.com/aphoto</a><a href="a link" target="_blank">Permalink</a> 1:32 PM - 16 Feb 2016<br><br>
```

I'm trying to sort the lines in the file by date. This is what I've cobbled together so far.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

when = re.compile(r".+</a>(.+)<br><br>")

with open('tweets.txt','r+') as outfile:
    sortme = outfile.read()

    for match in re.finditer(when, sortme):
        tweet = match.group(0)
        when = match.group(1)
        when = datetime.strptime(when, " %I:%M %p - %d %b %Y")
        print when
```

Which will print out all the dates in the lines having converted the format
from 1:40 PM - 17 Feb 2016 to 2016-02-17 13:40:00, which I believe is a datetime. I have searched high and low over the last few days for clues about how I'd then sort all the lines in the file by datetime. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> I have searched high and low over the last few days for clues about how I'd then sort all the lines in the file by datetime.

```
def get_time(line):
    match = re.search(r"</a>\s*(.+?)\s*<br><br>", line)
    if match:
        return datetime.strptime(match.group(1), "%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y")
    return datetime.min

lines.sort(key=get_time)
```

It assumes that the time is monotonous in the given time period (e.g., no DST transitions) otherwise you should convert the input time to UTC (or POSIX timestamp) first.

Comment: Thank You! Cool! (Alas as a noob I'm not able to further upvote your Answer)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have already solved the regex problem... so to convert your datetime into a measurable quantity convert to seconds like so:

```
import time
time.mktime(when.timetuple())
```

then for sorting you can make a lot off different routes. the simplest example is:

```
import operator
s = [("ab",50),("cd",100),("ef",15)]
print sorted(s,key=operator.itemgetter(1))
## [('ef', 15), ('ab', 50), ('cd', 100)]
```

Comment: 1- no need to convert datetime into seconds here. You can compare datetime objects directly 2- `mktime()` is incorrect unless the tweets use the local timezone for some reason.